# codeigniter active record against match error

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

why this will make an error?

```
$this->db->where('MATCH (title) AGAINST ("stackoverflow")', NULL, TRUE);
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'AGAINST
>   ("stackoverflow") LIMIT 4' at line 3
>
> SELECT * FROM (`table`) WHERE `MATCH`
>   (title) AGAINST ("stackoverflow")
>   LIMIT 4

when change to FALSE,the query will ok,but i want to protect mytable with with backticks

Comment: Can you post the whole active record method used? it might be your `select` method!

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL uses single quotes, not double quotes.

```
MATCH (title) AGAINST ('stackoverflow')
```

You can test whether this is really the problem with a string as your WHERE clause.

```
$where = "MATCH (title) AGAINST ('stackoverflow') LIMIT 4";
$this->db->where($where);
```